# Give write access to deploy key for new project created via gitpython

Tags: gitlab, gitpython

I have created a script using gitpython/python3 that creates a new project in a group and assigns our deploy key to the project. This all works perfectly, but I am not sure how to give the assigned key write access from the script. The relevant parts are below:

```
def add_deploy_key(project_id):    
    home = os.path.expanduser('~')
    gl = gitlab.Gitlab.from_config('redacted', ['%s/.python-gitlab.cfg' % home])
    project = gl.projects.get(project_id)
    DEPLOY_KEY_ID = redacted


    try:
        project.keys.enable(DEPLOY_KEY_ID)
        print("Your project has been created.")
    except:
        print("Failed to assign deploy key.")
```

Again, this works but does not give the assigned key write access to the new project. Also please excuse my sloppy error handling - not done yet.

Looked through gitpython documentation with no luck.

No error as the existing code works, but write access is not enabled.